# how to install same set of files in different folders

Tags: install4j

I am a newbie with installation products ie., install4j

I am having trouble getting a same set of files installed in different folders ( based on their existence )

say for following three folders

C:\company\lib
C:\company\32bit\lib
C:\company\64bit\lib

if they are present; then I should copy a set of jars there.

I tried having three different "Install files" section under Installation component.  At any point of time I am getting only one set of "Install files" getting to work. ie., if I have lib and 64bit\lib.. then it is getting copied one of the folders and proceeds with the Program Group...

Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure different file sets on "Files->Define distribution tree". See [this help topic](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/concepts/files.html) for an explanation.